# "Other keywords are not allowed when the 'Name' keyword is specified." No Name definied

Tags: c#, web-services, entity-framework

I'm keep getting this exception in a small application that im writing. I cant really find the reason, but think that im doing something wrong.

The code for tests looks like that:

```
public string GenerateConnectionString()
    {
        var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = Properties.Resources.SERVER_NAME,
            InitialCatalog = Properties.Resources.DB_NAME,
            UserID = Properties.Resources.DB_USER,
            Password = Properties.Resources.DB_PW,
            MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
            ApplicationName = "EntityFramework",
            IntegratedSecurity = false
        };

        string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

        var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
            ProviderConnectionString = providerString,
            Metadata = @"res://*/PcsDb.csdl|res://*/PcsDb.ssdl|res://*/PcsDb.msl"
        };

        testconnection(entityBuilder.ToString());

        return entityBuilder.ToString();
    }

private void testconnection(string connectionString)
    {
        var con = new EntityConnection(connectionString);

        con.Open();
        con.Close();

        tabMitarbeiter mitarbeirter;

        using (var context = new PCSEntities(connectionString))
        {
            mitarbeirter = (from mitarbeiter in context.tabMitarbeiter select mitarbeiter).FirstOrDefault(
                        elt => elt.UserID == "santos");
        }
    }
```

In the using (mitarbeiter = (from [...]) I always get the same exception:

```
Other keywords are not allowed when the 'Name' keyword is specified.
```

> at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>      at System.Linq.Queryable.Select[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
>      at PCSDB.PcsDb.testconnection(String connectionString) in d:\Projects\GlauxSoft.PCS.WebService\PCSDB\PcsDb.cs:line 134
>      at PCSDB.PcsDb.GenerateConnectionString() in d:\Projects\GlauxSoft.PCS.WebService\PCSDB\PcsDb.cs:line 118
>      at PCSDB.PcsDb..ctor() in d:\Projects\GlauxSoft.PCS.WebService\PCSDB\PcsDb.cs:line 15
>      at JiraSync.JiraSync..ctor(String name, DateTime date) in d:\Projects\GlauxSoft.PCS.WebService\Jira Sync\JiraSync.cs:line 14
>      at GlauxSoft.PCS.WebService.PcsService.JiraSync(String userName, DateTime datum) in D:\Projects\GlauxSoft.PCS.WebService\GlauxSoft.PCS.WebService\PcsService.svc.vb:line 799
>      at SyncInvokeJiraSync(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)

I did create a new constructor in the context class so that I can pass the connectionstring. And the EntityConnection can be opened and closed, but as soon as I try to get some data I get the exception.

As I said at the beginning, im pretty sure that its a mistake on my side, as its the first time that im using a dynamic connection in EntityFramework.

Comment: Can you post the constructor for PCSEntities?

Comment: Thank you for that question... I just saw my mistake. Had "public PCSEntities(string connectionstring) : base("name="+connectionstring)" instead of "public PCSEntitties(string connectionstring) : base(connectionstring)"

Comment: It is the context constructor that throws the error. you should pass the fully qualified connection string or the connection string name from config file to the context constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try simplifying the connection `Metadata`:

```
Metadata = @"res://*/"
```

Also, make sure that your resources have the same name as your `Model`.

Comment: Should have said that, already tried it multiple times, doesnt change anything.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the assembly names explicitly in the meta data string? (instead of using the wildcard)